# Policy change not reflecting immediately

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Whenever I make a change to my Azure AAD B2C policy, either a basic one from the Azure portal or a custom policy, I did not seem to observe the change immediately when running it through my web application or mobile application. It usually takes a few minutes before the change takes effect. This is quite inconvenient for me to test my web application as well as my mobile application.

Answer (score 11):

Azure Active Directory B2C uses cache to improve the performance of your Production traffic. As a side effect, the change to your policy won't take effect immediately as the service may still keep an old copy of your policy file. This usually takes 1-2 minutes.
However, the cache will be disabled if you run your user journey through the "Run Now" button in the Azure B2C portal blade. We recommend testing your policy through that "Run Now" button so you will observe the change to your policy file immediately.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit frustrating that this is not specified anywhere that I could find on the main docs. The changes also take much longer than 1-2 minutes in my experience.

Comment: how does `run now` "fix" this ?  Maybe the `&prompt=login` query parameter it adds?